# ExpandableList example not displaying correctly

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm following this tutorial: [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

But in my device (Samsung Galaxy S i9000) the text overlaps with the expandable icon as shown in the picture.

[image]

How can I avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example is kind of funky and I'm not sure why they're doing their layouts the way they are, but if you find this line:

```
textView.setPadding(36, 0, 0, 0);
```

Change that first value to something bigger. That'll change the left padding of the `TextView` which will stop the overlap. Again, that's not the greatest example for best practices in laying out views.